# Nested Observable Object in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I have an Object having two properties one string and another object. I am unable to create observable on object correctly using KnockOutJS. I do not know what mistake I am performing.

Here is my exact requirement: When I hover on `Data Source` it should show me all the configured DataSources and once I click on any one of them it `Data Source` should change to selected Data Source.

**JS**

```
function View(data) {
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    console.log("View : " + this.Name());
    this.DataSource = ko.observable();
    if (data.DataSource) {
        this.DataSource(new DataSource(data.DataSource));
        console.log("View.DataSource.Name" + this.DataSource.Name());
    }
}

function DataSource(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    console.log("DataSource : " + this.Name());
}

function ViewController() {
    var self = this;

    self.View = new View({
        Name: 'Untitled',
        DataSource: null
    });
    self.View.DataSource(new DataSource({}));

    self.DataSources = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.HideDS = function () {
        console.log("Hide");
        jQuery("#SelectDataSource").hide();
    }
    self.ShowDS = function () {
        console.log("Show");
        jQuery("#SelectDataSource").show();
    }
    self.SelDS = function (DS) {
        self.HideDS();
        self.View.DataSource(new DataSource(DS));
    };

    var GetDataSourcesSuccess = function (data) {
        self.DataSources(jQuery.map(data, function (item) {
            return new DataSource(item);
        }));
    }
    GetDataSourcesSuccess([{
        Name: "DS A"
    }, {
        Name: "DS B"
    }])
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewController());
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="event: { mouseover: ShowDS } , text: View.DataSource.Name == undefined? 'Data Source' : View.DataSource.Name "></button>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm hidden-selector" id="SelectDataSource" data-bind="foreach: DataSources , event: { mouseover: ShowDS , mouseout: HideDS }" style="display:none;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="text: Name, click: $parent.SelDS"></button>
</div>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/techphernalia/LDpgL/9/

Problem solved

**JS**

```
self.SelDS = function (DS) {
    self.HideDS();
    self.View.DataSource(new DataSource(DS));
};
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="event: { mouseover: ShowDS } , text: View.DataSource().Name()? View.DataSource().Name() : 'Data Source' "></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle, modifying the update of the observable as well as the logic to show the selected data source on the button:

### [Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDpgL/59/)

Updated selection function:

```
self.SelDS = function (DS) {
    self.HideDS();
    self.View.DataSource(DS);
};
```

Updated HTML with additional simple span to output the selection:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
        data-bind="event: { mouseover: ShowDS } , 
                   text: View.DataSource().Name() ? 
                         View.DataSource().Name : 
                         'Data Source' "></button>
...
<span data-bind="text: View.DataSource().Name() ? 
                       View.DataSource().Name : 
                       'No Selection Made'"></span>
```

Comment: There was one (`DataSource`)

Comment: Can't blame you since there is a *DataSource* prop and a *DataSource* ***s*** prop :)

Comment: You are creating `SelDataSource` and storing Selected DataSource over there. It is one of the property and I have multitude of them. So is it possible to access `View.DataSource` and not `SelDataSource`. Like we have `observableArray` for array and `observable` for valuetype, is there something for Object types as well?

Comment: Thanks Mate. It worked. Thanks a lot. So my mistake was in setting them rather than `self.View.DataSource(new DataSource(DS))` I have to use `self.View.DataSource(DS)`

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary `DS` is already the correct type so doesn't need to be new-ed up